# Adding up of same rows from multiple csv file, but categorised through recipe within a time frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sum

I have form anywhere 20 to 300 csv file per month that i need to get the total volume[m3] from the files, but do to the nature that the data is needed, i need to be able to categorise the sum of the csv file under the recipe name within the time frame of a month, the time frame can be fix with setting the csv file in folders for the months, but the recipe name need to be read and sorted with the total volume [m3]

currently i've havent found a way to do so, what i currently do is read the files in only...

```
def read_csv_files(folder_path):
    # Get a list of all CSV files in the specified folder
    csv_files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith(".csv")]

    for csv_file in csv_files:
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, csv_file)
        read_csv_file(file_path)

def read_csv_file(file_path):
    test = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='";', header=[0, 13], nrows=0, engine='python', encoding='ANSI')
    print(test)

    
folder_path = "C:\\Users\\nw\\Documents\\Mini projects\\CSV"
read_csv_files(folder_path)
```

my csv file is like this:

> Recipe;water
> Batch no;99
> Order no;3
> Serial no;F1200 1406545
> Company;Card
> Purchaser;
> Truck no;
> Job designation;
>
> Batch start;DT#2023-10-30-12:05:01
> Batch end;DT#2023-10-30-12:07:57
> Mixing time[s];12
> Act. WCT;0.0
> Set p. WCT;0.0
> Total volume[m ];0.1
> Total weight[kg];2.2
> Concrete type no;
> Strength class;
> Consistency range;
> Largest grain;
> Cement type;
> Additive;
> Admixture;
> Last batch in order;TRUE
> Manuel activated;TRUE
> Alarms:
> ERROR_RecycleValve_PosMixerNotOn
> ERROR_bDOSING_TOLERANCE_WATER1
> ExtraText;

tried to add it to a list/array as found from another post on here, but since my data is made in a different way than normal csv is i didnt get what anything out of it really

Ive tired to follow a example form another post on here but do to how my csv files are made it doesnt make that way possible.

the output of my print(df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [(Recipe;water, Total volume[m³];0.1)]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [(Recipe;Gulv og konstruktioner udvendig kl. M C30/37, Total volume[m³];0.35)]
Index: []

Comment: Please post a sample of your data in dataframe format and expected output

Comment: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [(Recipe;water, Total volume[m³];0.1)]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [(Recipe;Gulv og konstruktioner udvendig kl. M C30/37, Total volume[m³];0.35)]
Index: []

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to help without a sample of the data.

First you need to create a new column of the month. I am assuming that you take it from "Batch Start" and the format is a string:

```
df['month'] = df['Batch start'].str.split('-')[1]
```

Now you can use `groupby` to sum by Recipe and Month:

```
df.groupby(['Recipe', 'Month']).sum()
```

Let me know if this worked for you

Comment: my data is in there but here you have it
Recipe;water
Batch no;99
Order no;3
Serial no;F1200 1406545
Company;Card
Purchaser;
Truck no;
Job designation;

Batch start;DT#2023-10-30-12:05:01
Batch end;DT#2023-10-30-12:07:57
Mixing time[s];12
Act. WCT;0.0
Set p. WCT;0.0
Total volume[m�];0.1
Total weight[kg];2.2
Concrete type no;
Strength class;
Consistency range;
Largest grain;
Cement type;
Additive;
Admixture;
EPD;0.00E0;0.00E0;0.00E0;0.00E0;0.00E0;
EPDLink;
Last batch in order;TRUE
Manuel activated;TRUE
Power[%];7.141331
Material;Set p.;Act.;Dev;Moist;Unit

Comment: but it doesnt seem so
  File "C:\Users\nw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3790, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "index.pyx", line 152, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "index.pyx", line 181, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7080, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

Comment: File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7088, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Batch start'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\nw\Documents\Mini projects\ReadCSV.py", line 46, in <module>
    read_csv_files(folder_path)
  File "c:\Users\nw\Documents\Mini projects\ReadCSV.py", line 33, in read_csv_files
    read_csv_file(file_path)

Comment: File "c:\Users\nw\Documents\Mini projects\ReadCSV.py", line 38, in read_csv_file df['month'] = df['Batch start'].str.split('-')[1]
File "C:\Users\nw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3893, in __getitem__indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
File "C:\Users\nw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3797, in get_loc raise KeyError(key) from err

Comment: KeyError: 'Batch start'

Comment: as I stated above. Please post the data in dataframe format

Comment: like this on below ?

Comment: No. Post the output of : 'print(test)'

Comment: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [(Recipe;water, Total volume[m³];0.1)]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [(Recipe;Gulv og konstruktioner udvendig kl. M C30/37, Total volume[m³];0.35)]
Index: []